# Get rid of border for Top Tab (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native

I am using react-navigation, and when I use top-tab and stack, I get this border.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQaM.png)

How Do I remove this? 
My code looks something like this

```js
const ShoutoutTopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const ShoutoutTopTabScreen = () => {
  return (<ShoutoutTopTab.Navigator
    tabBarOptions={{
      indicatorStyle: {backgroundColor:'#4A6159'},
      tabStyle: {}
    }} >
    <ShoutoutTopTab.Screen name="GLOBAL" component={GlobalShoutout}/>
    <ShoutoutTopTab.Screen name="COUNTRY" component={CountryShoutout}/>
  </ShoutoutTopTab.Navigator>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who still has the issue, Try:

(tested in material-top-tabs 5.3.14)

```
tabBarOptions = {{
  style: {
  shadowOpacity: 0
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
tabBarOptions = {{
  indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: '#4A6159' },
  tabStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  }
}} >
```

Comment: didnt fix the issue :(

Comment: Try to add it in indicatorStyle

Comment: Still on luck :( I shouldn't be adding it to the indicator anyways because its the whole line, not just the indicator

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
}
```

Comment: I still get the line which is weird. It seems like its isn't a border

Answer (score 0):

What looks like a bottom border is actually a shadow.

```
tabBarOptions = {{
  style: {
  shadowOpacity: 0,
  elevation: 0,
  }
}}
```

This works for both IOS and Android. Tested on 5.3.15.